# Equivalency in Uniform and Pointwise Convergence

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

This will be a quick one, I know it exists somewhere, but I don't even know where to look.

Let's say we have a uniformly converging series of functions defined by $f_n$. Furthermore, we know that, for the pointwise convergent perfectly equivalent version of this series, $h_n$, it converges to some function, $g$. By this logic, can we say that the $f_n$ converges to $g$? If so, why?

Example: We see the pointwise convergence of $\sum_0^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ on $x \in (-1,1)$. Thus, if we prove that $f$ is uniformly convergent, can we say it also converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "perfectly equivalent"?

Comment: Suppose that on some set $S$ the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$ and uniformly to $g$. Assume there is some $x$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$. There is a positive integer $N$ so that $|f_N(x)-f(x)|<|f(x)-g(x)|/2$ and $|f_N(x)-g(x)|<|f(x)-g(x)|/2$. So $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq |f(x)-f_N(x)| + |f_N(x)-g(x)| < |f(x)-g(x)|$...

Comment: @hal4math I meant that it's the same base series. In both cases, it may be f_n = x^n, as an example. So I am wondering if it is pointwise convergent to 1/(1-x), and uniformly convergent, would it also converge to 1/(1-x) uniformly?

Comment: I am still a bit confused. What is the same base series? How may $h_n$ differ from $f_n$? Do you mean the following problem? Suppose you have am uniformly convergent sequence $f_n$ and you know it pointwise converges to $g$. Then yes, $f_n$ also converges uniformly to $g$. Uniform convergence is just a stronger requirement on the convergence, i.e. it implies also pointwise convergence. Since limits are unique (in metric spaces) they must coincide. @MattAPelto used a nice argument to show it concretely.

Comment: @hal4math Thank you, that is what I meant (with terrible wording)! MattAPelto did give a nice answer as well, so I thank you both!